# Modifying Depth First Search

Tags: algorithm

[image: DFS]----------

How would I modify the pseudocode for the depth-first search algorithm so that it prints out every edge in a directed graph G, as (source, destination) and it's type (tree, back, forward, cross)

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @user3460123 You should indicate the source site http://faculty.ycp.edu/~dbabcock/PastCourses/cs360/lectures/lecture17.html

Answer (score 0):

> How would I modify the pseudocode for the depth-first search algorithm so that it prints out every edge in a directed graph G

It's up to your using programming language and data type.

As for me, I like Ruby. So, I always create `Node` Struct to maintain edge information.

```
Node = Struct.new(:u, :k, :pi, :color)
```

- `:u` represents index of this node
- `:k` represents array of counter nodes

And, it will be created as `N` size `Array`. `N` is size of graph nodes.

```
@nodes = Array.new(n){ Node.new }
```

Once you prepared such data structure, you can retrieve those node information.

```
@nodes.each{|node| puts node.to_s}
```